# flutter firebase get string from database using future

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a string from my DB in Firebase, I'm very confused and I don't know how to do that!

I made a big search in the few past days about this idea but unf I don't get any useful result

what do I want? I want to make a Method that returns the 'Question' string.
DB:Collection / History/question

thank you for your time

the incorrect code :

```
Future loadData() async {

await Firebase.initializeApp();
if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
              ),
            );
          }

          // Collection Data ready to display
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // Display the data inside a list view
            return snapshot.data.docs.map(
              (document) {
                return method(
                  document.data()['question'].toString().toString(),
                ); //Center(

                  
              },
            );
          }
```

}

Comment: Okay, which database you use? Cloud firestore or Realtime?

Comment: its just cloud firestore, because the quizz question stored in the db and its not important to use relatime data loading

Comment: okay give me few seconds please.

Comment: its okey take your time, also i m thinking about solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Here is the official documentation from Flutter Fire - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

---

### Read data from Cloud firestore

Cloud Firestore gives you the ability to read the value of a collection or a document. This can be a one-time read or provided by real-time updates when the data within a query changes.

#### One-time Read

To read a collection or document once, call the `Query.get` or DocumentReference.get methods. In the below example a FutureBuilder is used to help manage the state of the request:

```dart
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

To learn more about reading data whilst offline, view the Access Data Offline documentation.

#### Realtime changes

FlutterFire provides support for dealing with real-time changes to collections and documents. A new event is provided on the initial request, and any subsequent changes to collection/document whenever a change occurs (modification, deleted, or added).

Both the `CollectionReference` & `DocumentReference` provide a `snapshots()` method which returns a Stream:

```dart
Stream collectionStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ABC123').snapshots();
```

Once returned, you can subscribe to updates via the listen() method. The below example uses a StreamBuilder which helps automatically manage the streams state and disposal of the stream when it's no longer used within your app:

```dart
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
}

class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
              subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

By default, listeners do not update if there is a change that only affects the metadata. If you want to receive events when the document or query metadata changes, you can pass includeMetadataChanges to the snapshots method:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and i have a question, in your example you use `FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>` as a widget ... how to use future as a function return the string value?

Comment: Use stream! wait I'll put an example here

Comment: Cloud firestore works like Custom model classes, So you can't get a string directly frm there, maybe you can by using it as REST-API. Okay Answer is: you have to create a `Stream collectionStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();` right? And then you have Future builder or Stream builder, so by using packages of flutter fire you can't put value directly, you have to use Future or Stream builders.

Comment: As i mentioned, create a Stream for your collection and wrapp your Text widget with Stream or future builder, then put snapshot's value to your text val.

Comment: This post would help you to get more about Firebase/Cloud https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40

Comment: thank you for your answer and explain its very helpful for me to understand the firestore and future builder

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to solve your problem.

Comment: actually i have a small issue about calling `firebasefirestore instance` its about `Firebase.initializeapp` and now im looking for solution in the previous questions

Comment: Just ask a new question, i will take care

Comment: Not at all. When you done about creating new question, just put a url in there, then I can see it.